# Can't perform pod install on flutter project in apple m1 chip

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, apple-m1, pod-install

I had recently made a flutter project and moved that project to my new mac mini with m1 chip. I have managed to install flutter, cocoapods,ffi etc but when i run pod install on the ios folder of my project it show this error,

```
46: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    45: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    44: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    43: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    42: from /Users/ananthan/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    41: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    40: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    39: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    38: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    37: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    36: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    35: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/earlgrey-1.16.0/lib/earlgrey/extensions/analyzer_extensions.rb:23:in `analyze'
    34: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    33: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    31: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    30: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
    29: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /Users/ananthan/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /Users/ananthan/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Users/ananthan/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
```

can anyone help me with this. The project won't run without pod install

Comment: same problem here

Comment: I tried MERELY EVERYTHING but couldn't find solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this steps.

1. sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
2. arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: i had done it but still that error is there

Comment: This solution I believe installs everything but as x86 binaries. Does debugging and building the project work after doing this?

Comment: This solved my problem. Also debugging and building works fine. 

I've created aliases in my `~/.zshenv` as follows `alias gem='arch -x86_64 gem'` The same goes for the pod command `alias pod='arch -x86_64 pod'`

Answer (score 1):

Follow these commands:

```
sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
sudo gem install cocoapods 
brew install chruby ruby-install
brew reinstall chruby
brew reinstall ruby-install
ruby-install ruby
ruby -v
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
brew reinstall cocoapods
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
pod init
pod install
pod update
```